# How to merge two arrays as key/val

Tags: javascript

How can you merge two arrays into key/value pairs please?

From this...

```
array1 = ['test1', 'test2'];
array2 = ['1', '2'];
```

To this...

```
array3 = ['test1':'1', 'test2':'2'];
```

Comment: The syntax of `array3` you provided isn't "key-value" syntax.

Comment: I think for your result you mean `array3 = {'test1':'1', 'test2':'2'};`, don't you? If so, then the answer with the phpjs array_combine will do just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://phpjs.org/functions/array_combine:307

EDIT: Looking at your question again, you might be after something more like this:

```
function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    var l = Math.min(arr1.length,arr2.length),
            ret = [],
            i;

    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
       ret.push(arr1[i]+":"+arr2[i]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Note I edited this entirely by accident, and am trying to figure out how to undo it. I can't seem to, so reviewer please reject, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using underscore.js http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#zip you can simply do:

```
var zipped = _.zip(array1,array2);
_(zipped).map(function(v){ return v[0] + ":" + v[1] });
```

Comment: Nope, look at the request - the op wants an object, you return an array of "key:value" strings.

Comment: Well, I think. Op is kinda cryptic since they accepted the answer above, which does the same thing. And this was half a year ago... blerg.

Comment: Wasted hours trying to do this with pure JS.  underscore to the rescue, wow.

Comment: Lodash offers [_.zipObject](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject) as well.