# Conditional merge 2 two dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js

I have 2 Arrays,

```
arr1 = [
    ['itemid-1', 'itemclass', 'timestamp'],
    ['itemid-2', 'itemclass', 'timestamp'],
    ['itemid-3', 'itemclass', 'timestamp'],
    ['itemid-5', 'itemclass', 'timestamp']
];

arr2 = [
    ['itemid-1', 'data-state', 'data-col'],
    ['itemid-3', 'data-state', 'data-col'],
    ['itemid-4', 'data-state', 'data-col']
];
```

The end result should be:

```
arr1 = [
    ['itemid-1', 'itemclass', 'timestamp', 'data-state', 'data-col'],
    ['itemid-2', 'itemclass', 'timestamp'],
    ['itemid-3', 'itemclass', 'timestamp', 'data-state', 'data-col'],
    ['itemid-5', 'itemclass', 'timestamp']
];
```

I want to merge values from `arr2` to `arr1` where `itemid-x` are same.

I can do this by using loops,

```
for(i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
        if(arr1[i][0] == arr2[j][0]){
            arr1[i] = arr1[i].concat(arr2[j].slice(1));
        }
    }

}
```

however I have recently started with [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) and nodejs, so I would like to know if it can be done with any existing functionality.

PS: I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916930/1618713) interesting, but it requires the length of the arrays to be same, also it won't work if the `itemid-x` indices are not same in both arrays.

Comment: So your code works and you just want to look for a neater way to do it?

Comment: Yes Of course, also I am already using underscore, and don't mind adding other libraries.

Comment: Your code uses native JavaScript functions. IMHO, you don't need anything else, just use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it really makes things look better or simpler to understand, but you can do

```
arr1.forEach(function(v, i){arr2.filter(function(v2){return v[0]==v2[0]}).forEach(function(v3){v3.slice(1).forEach(function(e){v.push(e)})})});
```

That for sure looks much more like js. ;)

I think there are so many different data structures and use cases that you can't really derive a common case from your data structure. element [0] is somehow special, but that is reflected in your code, not in the data structure.

To to something like considered in the answer you found interesting, can you restructure your data? `arr2 = { itemid-1: [ ... ], itemid-2: [ ... ] }`. Then you could do a forEach-loop, a simple lookup and a concat: `arr1[i].concat(arr2[v])`?

Comment: Thanks, I also ended up changing the arr2 to object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works alright, but you can improve upon this. Since you are using sorted arrays, you don't need two loops, which use `m*n` iterations. You can do it `m+n` iterations to merge two arrays where  m = `arr1.length` and n = `arr2.length`

```
var i = j = 0;
var answer = [];

while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length)
{
    arr1ptr = arr1[i][0];  // Just for checking index
    arr2ptr = arr2[j][0];  // You can extract 'id' if you want

    if (arr1ptr == arr2ptr)
    {
        answer.push(arr1[i].concat(arr2[j].slice(1)));
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if (arr1ptr < arr2ptr)
    {
        answer.push(arr1[i]);
        i++;
    }
    else if (arr1ptr > arr2ptr)
    {
        answer.push(arr2[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

It has more lines than yours, but it is faster. Depending on size of arrays you use and ease of coding, you may want to use it.

Comment: This is good, but the arrays are not always sorted (also must preserve index). Apologies as my example might have led to believe that. Again I want elements from arr1 if not matched, while arr2 elements should be discarded. For that I would change `else if (arr1ptr < arr2ptr)` to `else`, third condition is not required.